# Checking if the object passed to a method is "this"

Tags: c++, class, methods

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose I'm writing some class that has a method `myMethod` which modifies both `*this` and the argument passed:

```
class MyClass {
    //some code here
    void myMethod(MyClass& other) {
        //modify *this and other
    }
};
```

The problem is that I want that method to do nothing when the following piece is called:

```
MyClass x;
x.myMethod(x);
```

Checking for equality is not enough, because I want to be able to call it for two identical objects.

In a more down-to-earth way, for example, suppose that `MyClass` is something like `std::set` and `myMethod` merges two sets, emptying `other`. Two identical sets can be merged, but I obviously can't empty and fill one set at the same time.

How can I check for this? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can just compare the address of `other` to `this`:

```
class MyClass {
    //some code here
    void myMethod(MyClass& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            //modify *this and other
        }
    }
};
```

Since you pass by reference, the pointers will be equal if you pass the same object to the function as the one you called it on.

Comment: That simple. Obviously I misunderstood `this`

Comment: @Jytug, there are issues with using only addresses here, see my (downvoted for unclear reason) post.

Comment: @SergeyA I guess you're talking about the copy-and-swap idiom, but this isn't really the same thing (I didn't downvote you though).

Comment: How is it different? Copying objects from one set to another is a potentially throwing operation by definition. If it happens, you end up with half-done job.

Comment: @SergeyA: I think you need an introductory sentence along the lines "These difficulties you describe are similar to the difficulties in writing a copy assignment operator... you can use ideas from the 'copy and swap' idiom to achieve exception safety here." in order to make the answer easier to read. I see that you are right that the OPs question is very similar to copy assignment operator, but unless you read OPs question very carefully you might not see it that way immediately, and then it just seems that your answer is not much related to question.

Comment: @SergeyA The exception-safety consideration is the same as the usual `operator=` example, but the performance considerations are a bit different. For standard copy-and-swap, you copy from the object (which you would do anyway) and do a (hopefully cheap) swap. For a fully exception-safe implementation of this, you would need to make an entire copy of the first set, an entire copy of the second set, merge and swap, when this could just move elements from set 2 to set 1 if the code is hot and you don't forsee any exceptions. There are more things to consider in this case.

Comment: @TartanLlama, and I am not disputing the fact that address checking is useful as performance optimization (have this in my answer as well). However, OP is obviously and rightfully asking about correctness - and address checking does not provide full correctness.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, thanks for the suggestion, I do like it!

Answer (score 4):

You may check the address of the object. If they are identical,return or throw exception or whatever:

```
class MyClass {
    //some code here
    void myMethod(MyClass& other) {
        if(this==&other){
             //return or throw
        }
        //modify *this and other
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple

```
If (&other == this)
    .....your code......
```

Answer (score 2):

These difficulties you describe are similar to the difficulties in writing a copy assignment operator. Basically, address checking alone, while usefull performance optimization, is not enough to achieve full correctness of the operation in presence of exceptions. You can use ideas from the 'copy and swap' idiom to achieve exception safety here.

Following is an example of the code:

```
void MyClass::foo(MyClass& other) {
    MyClass tmp(this);
    tmp.add_from(other);
    other.empty();
    swap(tmp, *this);
}
```

Here swap needs to make sure to never throw exceptions. You can still compare address in the beginning, but it would only be a performance optimization, not the actual safety mechanism.